# Consistent estimator of $p^2$

Tags: convergence, consistency, point-estimation

> $(X_1, X_2,...,X_n)$ is a random sample of size $n$ from $Bernoulli(p)$ distribution. $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$. I have to check whether $\frac{S_n(S_n-1)}{n(n-1)}$ is a consistent estimator for $p^2$.

$S_n \sim Bin(n, p)$ and let $\bar X= \frac{Sn}{n}$

So, $E(\bar X)\rightarrow p$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ and $V(\bar X) \rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, and hence, $$\bar X \xrightarrow{P} p$$

Due to invariance under continuous function, $$\bar X^2 \xrightarrow{P} p^2$$

Now, $\frac{S_n(S_n-1)}{n(n-1)} =\frac{\bar X (\bar X -\frac{1}{n})}{1-\frac{1}{n}} \rightarrow \bar X^2$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and $\bar X^2 \xrightarrow{P} p^2$, so $$\frac{S_n(S_n-1)}{n(n-1)} \xrightarrow{P} p^2$$

Is this correct? To be precise, if $a(x) \rightarrow b(x)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and $b(x) \xrightarrow{P} c$, then can we say that $a(x) \xrightarrow{P} c$?

If this is not correct, then how can I show that the given estimator is inconsistent for $p^2$? If I can show that this estimator is consistent for some other function of $p$, does that mean that it is inconsistent for $p^2$? Or **can one estimator be consistent for more than one parametric functions?**

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can use the delta method to show that variance of the estimator goes to zero; it is already unbiased for $p^2$. This would prove consistency.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Yes, but the calculation of variance of the estimator will involve more time and effort, I think, since covariance terms will be there. Can you tell me if $a(x) \rightarrow b(x)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and $b(x) \xrightarrow{P} c$, then can we say that $a(x) \xrightarrow{P} c$?

Comment: @StubbornAtom How can I use delta method here to show that the variance goes to zero? Can you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: If you take $g(x)=\frac{x(nx-1)}{n-1}$ for $x\in(0,1)$, then by delta method, $\operatorname{Var}\left[g(\overline X)\right]\approx \frac1n[g'(p)]^2p(1-p)$ for large $n$ after which you can take the limit. This holds for $g'(p)\ne 0$.